# Connect to MYSQL using C

Tags: mysql, c, windows

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<mysql.h> 
int main() 
{ 
       printf("%s",mysql_get_client_info());
       return 0; 
}
```

When I compile this code, I get

> error : undefined reference to
>    'mysql_get_client_info@0'

I am using Code::Block in windows 7 (32bit) , mysql-connector-c-6.1.5-win32  and MySQL (5.0).  What is wrong I can't find ( this is new for me) . What are the steps that I should follow.

Used [this](https://jhrokku1022.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/codeblocks-c-in-win-7-connects-to-mysql-in-linux/) method to connect to mysql database for this  code :

Comment: Code that I executing :-

#include<stdio.h>
#include<mysql.h>
int main()
{
 printf("%s",mysql_get_client_info());
 return o;
}

Comment: Welcome to SO!! Please learn to format your question properly. This time, it's free . :-)

Comment: This is linker error. Check if your mysql library is at path which you set. Otherwise, you can try to compile this example without Code::Block using just command line.

Comment: Thankyou :)   (Anto)
Yes that was linker error. I was not adding '-lmysql' in other linker option box. 
It executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou :) (Anto) Yes that was linker error. I was not adding `-lmysql` in other linker option box. It executed successfully. –  Ibrahim_Miya